# Access 2013 Select Page to Output to PDF

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

In VBA I have no problem selecting report pages to send to a printer, but cannot do this sending to a PDF file using:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, reportName2, True
```

I am thinking the best way to do this after previewing a report may be to ask the user to select a page, then re-display the preview showing only that page, and then using `OutputTo` to send it to the PDF file.

However, I cannot figure out how to display a specific page in preview. Is this the right approach? If possible, any ideas, and if not, any suggestions?

Comment: Is specific page a filter of report? If so, filter report which will be one page and export to PDF.

Comment: No - no filter involved. The focus should be by page number after formatting and display, not the content of the page. I suppose a User could preview the report, move to the target page, and decide what data is shown at the start and end of that page. I could add programming to allow the user to input a start and end data point to create a filter, and then redisplay just that data (page) using it. The problem is I have over 100 reports, all based on different data and each would have to have a different filter based on the data - this is not practical.

Comment: Please provide more background so we can help you. What kind of report requires exactly one page per user without a filter? Couldn't future data extend beyond 1 page? You might be able to use Groups and page break by group, then apply a group filter?

Comment: These are contiguous multi-page reports (up to 50 pages), and each page shows a variety of data that may or may not be replicated on other pages. There is no way to group the data because of this, and each page is unique to the data shown. Users would like to change data for a particular page, create it as a pdf and distribute just the corrected/updated page rather than all the report pages. Of course they could do this if they have a pdf printer installed, but many of them don't, and don't want to install one. However, if that's the only answer, then so be it.

Comment: Is there any uniquely identifying column on data pages? Or rather, what indicators decides the different pages. This is your filterable/group-able field. If there isn't any how can they all be in one report and not separate? Is this an unbound report (I.e., no table/query recordsouce).

Comment: No - no unbound or columnar reports. Some of the key data may not be visible on the reports and not obvious to the user when viewing a page. I think you are missing the point. Even were it possible, with over 100 reports with many different underlying combinations of table data (many many tables) it is not practical to create an individual filter for each and then code report-specific options. If you believe I cannot preview the target page without a filter on the underlying data, then I guess there is no way to use the OutputTo command (which doesn't seem to support PrintDialog).

Comment: Without data, we cannot help. [DoCmd.OpenReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676.aspx) method has a *wherecondition* argument which can use any field(**s**) in report's recordsouce (visible or hidden) and once applied you can export that filtered one pager to PDF with `DoCmd.OutputTo`, all dynamically through code. Otherwise this is one magical report which for curiosity I would love to see! Good luck!

Comment: I take it from your comments that you believe the ability of a user to select a report page to print (e.g. using PrintOut or using the print dialog menu) is silly and should not have been included in Access. Strange ... your preoccupation with data filtering is baffling. It would be nice if Microsoft just provided the same feature to OutputTo instead of folks like me trying to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cute pdf writer..

This is a printer that convert output to pdf download from here-

http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp

Here is the command to send a specific page to printer-

[Printing a specific page from an Access Report](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/121870-Printing-a-specific-page-from-an-Access-Report)

If I where you I'll add a button on the top menu that would activate this function :

```
Public Function prtpdf() As Integer
    On Error GoTo err
    Dim repname As String, pagenum As String, strDeviceName   As String
    Dim prt As Printer
    ' Get current default printer
    Set prt = Application.Printer
    pagenum = InputBox("Please insert page number")
    If Not IsNumeric(pagenum) Then Exit Function
    ' Set default printer
    strDeviceName = "CutePDF Writer"
    Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(strDeviceName)
    'repname = Screen.ActiveReport.Name
    DoCmd.PrintOut PrintRange:=acPages, PageFrom:=pagenum, PageTo:=pagenum
    ' Restore original printer
err:
    Set Application.Printer = prt
End Function
```